# Flexbox wrap items on demand?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I currently have a model like this

```
 .parent
   .child1
   .child2
   .child3
   .child4
```

The request is: 'parent' is a row that takes full width of the device.

In big screen, there is one row with 4 children.

In smaller screen, there are 2 rows with 2 columns each.

And in the extra small screen there are 1 column with 4 rows.

Is there any way that I can achieve the request using only Flexbox? (because I hate Boostrap so much...)

I tried `flex-wrap: wrap` for the parent and `flex: 1` for the children, but failed :(

Thank you :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### This is a `SCSS` *mixin* that does that:

```
@mixin n-columns($min-width, $gutter, $last-equal:false, $max-cols:5, $selector:'.colItem'){
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    margin-left: -$gutter;
    // margin-top: -$gutter;
    position: relative;
    top: -$gutter;

    > #{$selector} {
        flex: 1 0 auto;
        margin-left: $gutter;
        margin-top: $gutter;

        @if $last-equal {
            @for $i from 2 through $max-cols {
                $screen-width: ($min-width*$i)+($gutter*$i);
                $column-width: (100%/$i);
                @media( min-width: $screen-width) {
                        max-width: calc(#{$column-width} - #{$gutter});
                }
            }

            $column-width: (100%/$max-cols);
            @media( min-width: $min-width*$max-cols) {
                    min-width: calc(#{$column-width} - #{$gutter});
            }
        }
    }
}
```

#### You use it like so:

```
.parent{
    @include n-columns(200px, 3px, true, 5);
}
```

You'll understand all the things it can do after you use it with different settings and see the results, it's pretty straightforward.

Comment: Thank you very much man! Will try it right now! Have a great day man!

Answer (score 1):

```css
.container {
    display: flex;
}

.box {
    flex: 1;
}

@media ( max-width: 800px ) {
  .container { flex-wrap: wrap; }
  .box { flex: 0 0 50%; box-sizing: border-box; }
}

@media ( max-width: 500px ) {
  .box { flex-basis: 100%; }
}

/* non-essential decorative styles */
.box {
    height: 50px;
    background-color: lightgreen;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    font-size: 1.2em;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="box"><span>1</span></div>
    <div class="box"><span>2</span></div>
    <div class="box"><span>3</span></div>
    <div class="box"><span>4</span></div>
</div>
```

### [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/j4ncw6s6/)

Comment: Had the feeling you will very quickly make a fiddle since the snippet wouldn't work on stackoverflow :) BUT it it's very automatic since many items require custom configuration, and you cannot guarantee the number of items you might have: https://jsfiddle.net/fLza31Lt/

Comment: Hi @vsync, thanks for the feedback. I was just going by the requirements in the question. The asker said there are only four children. (Also, if you expand the stack snippet to full screen, it will work fine for testing.)

Comment: while indeed the OP asked a specific question, but one cannot take it too literally, since he might have simply set the arbitrary number `4` as an anchor to the question. *and* people certainly gonna come here from google expecting a solution that fits in a more general manner. I know I come from google a lot and always get mad when i see an ad-hook answer that is not generalized (can't copy-paste and use)